# Mage.php not sending headers code line 766

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm new to both Magento and PHP. I'm using Magento CE 1.9 on a local server for testing for an upgrade to 1.9. When I load onto the localhost the following error appears -

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php, line 766

Trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1246): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; char...')
#2 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse()
#3 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(202): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse()
#4 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 C:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 C:\wamp\www\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

If I look at myphpadmin and copy the code from Mage.php near line 766 -

```
  765 if (is_readable($localConfigFile)) {
  766              $localConfig = simplexml_load_file($localConfigFile);
  767              date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
  768              if (($date = $localConfig->global->install->date) && strtotime($date)) {
  769                  self::$_isInstalled = true;
```

This is the text from my local.xml in notepad -

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Tue, 21 Aug 2012 16:37:58 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[fca5389338fe4588362c923c9abdff25]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[root]></username>
                    <password><![]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[magento]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[site_admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `simplexml_load_file` [throws a warning](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php#refsect1-function.simplexml-load-file-errors) and this causes the "headers already sent" error. So the config xml might be invalid. At least the `simplexml_load_file` produces some output. Take a look at `Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract::canSendHeaders`, where the exception is thrown.

```
public function canSendHeaders($throw = false)
{
   $ok = headers_sent($file, $line);
   if ($ok && $throw && $this->headersSentThrowsException) {
       #require_once 'Zend/Controller/Response/Exception.php';
       throw new Zend_Controller_Response_Exception('Cannot send headers; headers already sent in ' . $file . ', line ' . $line);
   }

   return !$ok;
}
```

Comment: Code in Abstract.php is exactly the same as above

Comment: @MatthewCaddis Sorry, I meant it as hint, that simplexml_load_file must produce some output before. Please validate your local.xml file.

Comment: The only thing I can see in my local.xml is that database doesn't have a password, I used root as username and the my magento database is "magento" which does have the tables  from a previous installation and can't be dropped in phpmyadmin and "magento2" which has no tables

Comment: I will go into phpmyadmin to look at at my password in the "magento2" database (The databases are the other way around- sorry!)

Comment: Looking at the admin_user table it appears there are two user names one so I may speak with my boss to see which is needed

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot send headers; headers already sent` is thrown when you have any output before the Magento application tries to send its headers. These premature outputs can be anything from `echo`, `print_r`, etc. to spaces before the `<?php` tag in PHP files that are loaded. I would check `$localConfigFile` to make sure the XML syntax is perfect.

Check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670031/magento-debug-headers-already-sent-error

Answer (score -1):

Please open your file in a Text editor like notepad++ and set encoding to UTF8 without BOM.

Comment: The posted `local.xml` does not contain any non-ANSI characters, so why would it make a difference?